# How to properly import Telegraf with typescript and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, telegraf.js

Why this code compiles fine

```
require('dotenv').config();
import { Markup, Scenes, session } from 'telegraf';
import { START_SCENE_ID, startScene } from './scenes/startScene';
const {Telegraf} = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN!);
const stage = new Scenes.Stage([startScene]);
bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
```

Whereas this does not compile

```
require('dotenv').config();
import { Telegraf, Markup, Scenes, session } from 'telegraf'; // <--- change is here
import { START_SCENE_ID, startScene } from './scenes/startScene';
// const {Telegraf} = require('telegraf'); <--- and here
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN!);
const stage = new Scenes.Stage([startScene]);
bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
bot.command('start', Scenes.Stage.enter(START_SCENE_ID));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try defining scene context to your bot as in [this example](https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/examples/scenes/scenes.ts)

There are multiple context types ([context](https://telegraf.js.org/classes/Context.html), [scene context](https://telegraf.js.org/interfaces/Scenes.SceneContext.html), [wizard context](https://telegraf.js.org/interfaces/Scenes.WizardContext.html)) and you'll need to set the proper one when creating the bot